# Laravel 5.5 Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to implement relationships between models and i recieve "Trying to get property 'products' of non-object" and i don't understand why, because i used this before in the same way and it's worked fine.

> The logic of relationship is that 1 Merchant hasMany Products

this is the code that i'm using:

Merchant Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Merchant extends Model {
    protected $table = "merchants";

    protected $fillable = [
        'merchant_id', 'merchant_name', 'secret_key', 'merchant_address', 'merchant_phone', 'merchant_admin',
        'merchant_contact', 'merchant_mail', 'merchant_description', 'enable', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function users() {

        //many to many
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function branchOffices() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\BranchOffice', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }

    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }

    public function transactions() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }

    public function readers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reader', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }

}
```

Product Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {
    protected $table = "products";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'barcode', 'description', 'price', 'currency_id', 'merchant_id', 'branch_id',
        'enable', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function merchants() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Merchant', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id');
    }

    public function currencies() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Currency', 'iso_4712', 'currency_id');
    }

    public function branch_sectors() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\BranchSector');
    }

}
```

And this is the method in ProductController:

```
public function merchantProducts() {

        $products = Merchant::find('merchant_id')->products;
        return $products;
    }
```

If someone can help me i'll be very thankfull.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what do you get if you do this  public function products() {
        dd($this->hasMany('App\Products', 'merchant_id', 'merchant_id'));
    }  ?

Comment: Hi! i don't unerstand... i mean... can i use dd direct from the model?
Because, when i tried to use it from the controller y recieve "Trying to get property 'products' of non-object" for some reason i can't call products() from the controller

Comment: You can use dd() anywhere in the code. I'm just trying to figure out the cause.

Comment: btw you can remove the $table = 'whatevers' as long as Model is Whatever and table is the plural of the model name

Comment: yes... but i don't see how call it, because i cant' call products()

Comment: i think i got it. Where is your primary key? if your primary key is merchnat_id it should not be in fillable. Just do it. I want to see if you get the same error.

Comment: oh, yes! i forgot this... i'll remove it right now

Comment: yes, merchant_id is the pk, but  if i'll remove it from fillable... can i use it with a normal crud ?

Comment: then protected $primaryKey = 'merchnat_id'; and is it auto increment?

Comment: if it's autoincrement remove it from fillable. same in products. Read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: no, it's not autoincrement because it's a string... the table has default mysql id (autoincrement) and merchant_id as pk

Comment: then add it as I said protected $primaryKey = 'merchnat_id';  before fillable and see if it works. Otherwise you cannot use find($merchantId)

Comment: of if you want to keep id as pk then do Merchant::where('merchant_id', $merchantId)->first()->products()

Comment: and this btw will never ever work  $products = Merchant::find('merchant_id')->products;
        return $products;
    } you need public function merchantProducts($id) {

        $products = Merchant::find($id)->products;
        return $products;
    }

Comment: ahh... ok... but in that case I will not be using the relationship ?

Comment: relationship will not be an issue. contact me in chat so I can give you more info

Answer (score 0):

Assume merchant is not guaranteed existing in database giving merchant id, it is better off to check if merchant exists, and retrieves its products if so.

```
$products = collect();
$merchant = Merchant::find($merchant_id);
if($merchant) {
    $products = $merchant->products;
}
return $products;
```

Answer (score 0):

all!!

Finally i solved this problem using resources in this way:

```
public function merchantProducts(Request $request) {

        $merchant_id = $request->merchant_id;

        $products = Product::where('merchant_id', $merchant_id)->paginate(15);

        return ProductResource::collection($products);

    }
```

Thanks to all!!